# Primefaces - How to redirect to mobile version?

Tags: redirect, mobile, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm created a website in JSF 2 (primefaces 3.3) and now I want to create a mobile version. I have diferents views for desktop/mobile. 
I already create a custom viewhandler to detect mobile browsers.
It seens to work fine. But what a don't understand is how to redirect the user to the mobile pages. I've searched a lot and nobody says where this step occurs.
In what step should i do that? Redirect the user, and how to?

Answer (score 8):

Do the browser detection job in a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) mapped on `FacesServlet` instead of in a `ViewHandler`.

It's then as easy as

```
if (needsRedirectToMobileURL) {
    response.sendRedirect(mobileURL);
}
else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

A `ViewHandler` isn't intented to manipulate the request/response. It's intented to handle the JSF view for the given request.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you do not want to redirect to a mobile site but instead use css media queries to determine what the browser size is and use different css for that.  Here is a quick example

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: +1 for the general answer. But primefaces has a mobile api/gui which has much different designs then the desktop version.